# React JS - react-toolbox Date Picker - disable some dates

Tags: reactjs, react-toolbox

React JS - react-toolbox Date Picker - disable some dates

Am using react js date picker. Need disable some dates. [date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7T7vc.png)

Source URL: http://react-toolbox.com/#/components/date_picker

Comment: Hi @Vinoth, what did you try?

Answer (score 1):

Answer is right infront of you on the docs. 
`disabledDates` - `Array` - An array of date objects which will be disabled in the calendar. All other dates will be enabled.

Comment: it's expecting a date object not a string